# How to multiply the values of two objects i.e. slider and number input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, object, innerhtml, multiplication

I want multiply the values of two objects in javascript and want to show in innerHtml of rangeV, But I am getting issues. Please help. The code is given below. Also, I have attached a picture of code and highlighted the issue.

```js
const range = document.getElementById("range"),
  rangeV = document.getElementById("rangeV"),
  inp5 = document.getElementById("myinput"),
  inp6 = inp5.value,
  inp7 = 2;

setValue = () => {
  const newValue = Number(
      ((range.value - range.min) * 100) / (range.max - range.min)
    ),
    newPosition = 10 - newValue * 0.2;
  var val1 = range.value * inp7;
  rangeV.innerHTML = `<span>${val1}</span>`;
  rangeV.style.left = `calc(${newValue}% + (${newPosition}px))`;

  // $(".forspace").html(range.value);
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setValue);
range.addEventListener("input", setValue);
```

Comment: What issues are you getting?

Comment: can you share full code, html part too. Also try adding "change" eventlistener to range if its slider instead of "input"

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add HTML to make a [mcve]